# Data factory: Trigger time using as a parameter in Relative URI in HTTP file datasets

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a REST source from where I am ingesting data. I have to trigger pipeline every 2am in the morning. So far so good. I have done this. But there is a parameter in Relative URI in which i have to put 'since time' in it. Basically it will send all the responses after "since time" (epoch time) hence its usability is significant.

So suppose if I am triggering it today morning 2am then I have to set "since time" in relative URI as (current datetime - 1 day).

Is there any way on how to use parameters of factory to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by using data factory's expressions and functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

In the dataset, you can combine a date function with the pipeline's trigger time to do the -1 day and format it as follows:

```
"url" : "<HTTP endpoint>/timeSince/@{formatDateTime(adddays(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1), 'yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm')}"
```

Modify it to meet your needs. To format the date see this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin. But I want it in epoch unix timestamp format. Is it possible anyway to do it?

Comment: I used this @{formatDateTime(adddays(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')} but it did not work :(

Comment: I also used @{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -1), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')}. Basically when it will trigger, triggerTime will be same as utcnow() right?

Comment: This is the API I am using and running a GET Request. In here you can see a 'since_time' parameter.    https://asknicely.asknice.ly/help/apidocs/responses      In here it asks me to put a unix timestamp. This API i have configured in HTTPFile dataset. So everyday at 2am this GET Request runs and extract the responses from the API. I just need to convert this 2am datetime into Unix format and pass it as a parameter in the URI.